# INSERT IGNORE or not bother?

Tags: mysql

In mysql I am inserting many duplicate records without using INSERT IGNORE and it is generating no error whatsoever. I have a primary key and a unique column.

Should I be using another alternative or is it safe to say that it is fine just to do an INSERT as it is generating no error upon a duplicate being inserted.

Comment: Why would you use insert ignore ? There is a reason for every tool..

Comment: As it is supposed to suppress errors generated from inserting a duplicate unique column value.

Comment: Exactly... You've just answered your own question! ^^ the unique colmn will not dupe..

Comment: Thanks. Is it not weird I am not receiving any errors though?

Comment: Error messages are not there to annoy programmers, it's just the opposite. If you choose to hide them, your debugging will become a long series of shots in the dark. Just my two cents...

Comment: you said you have `I have a primary key and a unique column.` if you try insert with dupe unuique id SQL just wont do it.. check your tables and you will see they're not the same.. Thats my suspicion anyway!